# Regex to list hidden files only with extension

Tags: regex, unix

I am looking for a regex to list out files starting with extension with no meaningful names.

Ex:
.txt
Team.txt

Now, how do I list out only .txt file rather than Team.txt too?

I tried "'^.txt$'" but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this help:`ls -d .*` ?

Comment: How come "^.txt$" does not work? what kind of regex do you use? With python regex it works: `>>> print re.match("^.txt$",".txt");
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x022859C0>
>>> print re.match("^.txt$","Team.txt");
None`

Comment: I tried both "'^.txt$' and '^\.txt$'" but doesn't seem to work. I apply these regex with GNU grep. I used both ksh and bash but for some reason I never got successful results.

Comment: what you want find out, just the hide file `.txt` ? If so you can try this `find .txt`

Comment: OK, few more tests. When I list dirs with ls -al | grep '^\.txt$' it doesn't work. If I pipe ls -al output into awk and take out only the name column then pipe it into grep it works perfectly. Can't I directly pipe ls results into grep regex?

Comment: @Würgspaß, `^.txt$` as a regexp matches **all** four char names ending in `txt`, not only the ones beginning with a dot.  Try `^\.txt$` instead.  It should match names like `atxt`, `btxt` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (without quotes when giving regex to grep):

```
ls -a | grep ^.txt
```